# Unknown column in 'on clause' error

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm trying to query three tables and can do two of three but not the third, I've tried several ways and keep getting this error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'thirdDATA.creator_id' in 'on clause'
```

This works:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `mainDATA` 
LEFT JOIN altDATA ON creator_id =  altDATA.creator_id
```

This works:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `mainDATA` 
LEFT JOIN thirdDATA ON creator_id =  thirdDATA.creator_id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This gets an error:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `mainDATA` 
LEFT JOIN altDATA ON creator_id =  altDATA.creator_id
JOIN thirdDATA ON creator_id =  thirdDATA.creator_id
```

Comment: The last unqualified `creator_id` reference is ambiguous...but the queries do not match your error message....so whether that is the reason for the error you are getting is unclear. (Also, having an unqualified field name in any query involving more than one table is just bad practice.)

Comment: Can you please modify the error message to match your table names.

Comment: Best practice is to qualify *all* column references. An error message from MySQL is expected behavior. Thanks for sharing the *status report*. Was there a ***question***?.

Comment: I don't see a table called `creators` in your query.

Comment: What the purpose of this query if the main table have no key to make join ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you have more than one table in a query, qualify *all* column names.

Presumably, you intend:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mainDATA LEFT JOIN
     altDATA
     ON mainDATA.creator_id =  altDATA.creator_id JOIN
     thirdDATA
     ON mainDATA.creator_id =  thirdDATA.creator_id;
```

The behavior you describe would work if `mainDATA` had no `creator_id`.  If that is the case, the first query would be interpreted as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `mainDATA` LEFT JOIN
     altDATA
     ON altDATA.creator_id =  altDATA.creator_id;
```

The third would generate an error because two tables have `creator_id` and it is unclear which the last `on` clause refers to.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the mainDATA table does have a creator_id. With your code i’m still getting error: #1054 - Unknown column 'mainDATA.creator_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: @rowdyruckus A demo of this method works: http://rextester.com/XMOEAP46400 - and the original queries fail with "Column 'creator_id' in on clause is ambiguous". So I'm not sure how you're getting an error - are these the exact queries or have they been paraphrased?

Comment: even just this part returns the same error: SELECT * 
FROM mainDATA LEFT JOIN
     altDATA
     ON mainDATA.creator_id =  altDATA.creator_id

Comment: @rowdyruckus  . . . Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

When mixing `JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`, use parentheses to override the precedence:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( `mainDATA` 
       LEFT JOIN altDATA ON creator_id =  altDATA.creator_id )
JOIN thirdDATA ON creator_id =  thirdDATA.creator_id
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM `mainDATA` 
LEFT JOIN ( altDATA
            JOIN thirdDATA ON creator_id =  thirdDATA.creator_id )
   ON creator_id =  altDATA.creator_id
```

Doing so will either fix your problem, or point out that `creator_id` is inaccessible because it is hiding inside parens.